# Share OpenGL code between Emscripten and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, emscripten

I'd like to share rendering code between my Emscripten-based frontend (Webgl2 aka GLES3.0) and my Qt frontend (OGL3.3, but wouldn't mind GLES3.0 there too, if feasible).
Both use exactly the same GL-calls, so i would like to move all calls to helper-functions that are then called from the frontend.

The problem is that to be portable, i want to call the functions from `GLES3/gl3.h` in the emscripten-part, while using `QOpenGLFunctions` in the Qt-part (or another, equally portable solution):

guiwrapper.cpp:

```
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
void drawStuff(){
    glDrawArrays(...); // taken from <GLES3/gl3.h>
}
```

emscripten.cpp:

```
#include <guiwrapper.h>
void someDrawFunc(){
    drawStuff(); // glDrawArrays pulled from <GLES3/gl3.h>
    glDrawArrays(...); // also correctly uses <GLES3/gl3.h> version
}
```

qt.cpp:

```
class guiwidget: public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions{
public:
    void paintGL(void);
}
void guiwidget::paintGL(){
     glDrawArrays(...); // correctly calls QOpenGLFunctions::glDrawArrays
     drawStuff(); // still uses <GLES3/gl3.h>
}
```

Is there a possibility to achieve this without writing all helper-functions as macros?

Comment: We had a similar topic: we had an OpenGL rendering library in a Qt desktop application which we wanted to use stand-alone (e.g. for an HMD application). After playing around with various complicated wrapper definitions of `QOpenGLFunctions` in `typedef`s etc. I finally used a rather simple and pragmatic solution. I got the "official header files" (from [Khronos](https://www.khronos.org/)), wrote an own binding for GL functions (probably with help of awk but any other "intelligent" text replacement tool will do as well) and use them instead of the Qt OpenGL stuff. This works fine.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I had to do the OpenGL API binding because I'm on Windows. (MS has canceled OpenGL support since OpenGL 2 to promote their own Direct3d stuff.) On other systems, e.g. Linux I would simply use the OpenGL API directly...

Comment: Things became a little bit complicated when we started to involve HUD drawing using the Qt painter. Being aware of [`QPainter::beginNativePainting()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#beginNativePainting) and [`QPainter::endNativePainting()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#endNativePainting), I had some crashs in `QPainter::drawText()`. Thus, I added code to restore OpenGL states (which were changed in my code) before HUD rendering. Finally, this solved the issue. (Qt internal rendering may use OpenGL as well and is quite sensitive if "you disturb its states".)

Comment: Thanks for your input! Yes, the Windows-part was where my previous approach failed. Even though the windows-qt-builds provide the GLES-headers (via QtANGLE), compilation fails...unfortunate situation, but glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found a satisfying solution, that's not completely devoid of preprocessor-magic, but at least there are neither macros nor code-duplication.
Maybe it helps someone:

guiwrapper.h:

```
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
class GuiWrapper
#else
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
class GuiWrapper: protected QOpenGLFunctions
#endif
{
    void drawStuff(void); // cpp decides between free and member-functions
};
```

emscripten.cpp:

```
#include <guiwrapper.h>
void someFunc(void){
    GuiWrapper gui;
    gui.drawStuff(); // calls <GLES3/gl3.h>
}
```

glwidget.cpp:

```
#include <guiwrapper.h>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
class GLWidget: public QOpenGLWidget, private GuiWrapper{
    public:
        void paintGL(void){
            drawStuff(); // calls <QOpenGLFunctions>
        }
};
```